# How do I retrieve the current and next record using SQLIte

Tags: sqlite

I know there's a way to write a SQL statement that gives the present and next record in the result set.  Lead only gives a column (or am I wrong). I need the whole record.

I'm creating a lottery program in Excel and using Querystorm which uses the SQLite database engine.  Querystorm, if you're not familiar with it, is an addon that lets you run SQL code against the tables in Excel.  It treats the tables as DB Tables using SQLite as an in memory database.  The problem with SQlite is the funky fried way it stores and retrieves dates.

It stores dates as strings and you have to format the string to be able to actually read the date.  Luckily, it does have a few functions to do this.

Anyway, the Table is very simple.  Draw Date, Ball 1, Ball 2, (etc etc,you know the routine).  How would I write a SQlite statement that retrieves the current and next record where a condition is met, say "Ball 1" = 5?  I need all the records where "5" is the first ball, and the results show the next record (in other words, the next drawing record after the one that equal 5).  Then the next time 5 was drawn and the record after that, and so on.  I feel a join happening, but its the Dates in SQLite that are giving me the most grief.

Comment: I'd search for [sqlite cursor](https://searx.be/search?q=sqlite+cursor).

Comment: "It stores dates as strings".  No, it [stores data as strings, floats, integers, or binary data](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).